# Angular routes not working as I would think

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do some `routing` in `Angular`, and so far I've been successful. However, I just ran into a problem.

The following line is working just fine

```
when('/shops/:shopId/:shopName', {
```

However, this route is not working:

```
when('/shops/:shopId/:shopName/collections', {
```

When I navigate to the second one, I get thrown to the `otherwise` route. No errors are displayed in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

More of the routing as requested:

```
when('/shops/:shopId/:shopName', {
    templateUrl: 'js/modules/shops/partials/shop.html',
    controller: 'ShopController',

    resolve: {

        shop: ['ShopService', '$route', '$q', function(ShopService, $route, $q) {

            var defer = $q.defer();

            ShopService.getShop($route.current.params.shopId).success(function(data) {

                defer.resolve(data);

            });

            return defer.promise;

        }]

    }
}).

when('/shops/:shopId/:shopName/collections', {
    templateUrl: 'js/modules/collections/partials/collections-brand.html',
    controller: 'CollectionsController',

    resolve: {
        collections: ['CollectionService', '$route', '$q', function(CollectionService, $route, $q) {

            var defer = $q.defer();

            CollectionService.getCollectionsByBrand($route.current.params.shopId).success(function(data) {

                defer.resolve(data);

            });

            return defer.promise;

        }]

    }
}).


/* End */

otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

Comment: Can you paste all the code related to this config? Also what url are you using to access the second one?

Comment: can we see the whole route?  I am not usre its that line.

Comment: I added more of the routing to the thread

Comment: Routes look ok, are you sure that the url you are typing is correct when trying to access the second route? Please paste it here

Comment: This route is working as intended:
`http://localhost/client/app/#/brands/1/justabrand`, and `http://localhost/client/app/#/brands/1/justabrand/collections` is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using html5Mode?  If so you might want to make sure everything is setup correctly there on your server with proper redirect, you have a base tag if needed, etc.  If it is being used you could also turn off html5Mode to eliminate any server setup issues.